# Doxygen undocumented string value

Tags: c++, doxygen

Doxygen (1.8.10) is complaining that the **value** of my string is not documented. Here's a minimal example that demonstrates the problem

```
#include <string>

struct MyStruct ///< Docs for struct
{
    std::string a; ///< Docs for a
    std::string b; ///< Docs for b
};

class MyClass ///< Docs for class
{
    static struct MyStruct instance; ///< Docs for instance
};

struct MyStruct MyClass::instance = {"firstVal", "secondVal"};
```

This results in the warning

```
/tmp/example.cpp:10: warning: Member firstVal (variable) of class MyClass is not documented.
```

If I reduce the struct to a single member and remove "secondVal" from the initializer, then the warning disappears, but obviously that's not a solution...

Comment: Does it work with universal initialization? I think that would be `struct MyStruct MyClass::instance {{"firstVal", "secondVal"}};`

Comment: That _almost_ worked, and has led me to a working solution (assuming C++11/GCC 4.4 or above, I'd love a more portable solution). `struct MyStruct MyClass::instance {{"firstVal"}, {"secondVal"}};` (with each string literal in it's own set of curly braces). The compiler will actually accept @AndrewLazarus 's example with this toy example, but it seems to be calling the wrong constructor! Compiler warnings are your friend here since it triggered `-Wmissing-field-initializers` (part of `-Wextra`) for the second arg...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just delete the extra `struct`. As in:

```
#include <string>

struct MyStruct ///< Docs for struct
{
    std::string a; ///< Docs for a
    std::string b; ///< Docs for b
};

class MyClass ///< Docs for class
{
    static struct MyStruct instance; ///< Docs for instance
};

MyStruct MyClass::instance = {"firstVal", "secondVal"};
```

C++ doesn't require you to use `struct MyStruct` and instead allows you to use just plain `MyStruct`. Making this tiny change makes the warning go away with doxygen 1.8.13.

Comment: Well see, now you've gone and made me feel silly for not trying this myself :)

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the `EXTRACT_ALL` tag in the doxyfile to `YES`, then the warning should disappear.

Also note the comment to the `EXTRACT_ALL` setting:

```
# If the EXTRACT_ALL tag is set to YES, doxygen will assume all entities in
# documentation are documented, even if no documentation was available. Private
# class members and static file members will be hidden unless the
# EXTRACT_PRIVATE respectively EXTRACT_STATIC tags are set to YES.
# Note: This will also disable the warnings about undocumented members that are
# normally produced when WARNINGS is set to YES.
# The default value is: NO.
```

*BTW one further tip:*

Don't use the `///<` comments for multi-line entities. The result of your documentation will look better if you comment your code this way:

```
/**
 * Docs for struct
 */
struct MyStruct 
{
    std::string a; ///< Docs for a
    std::string b; ///< Docs for b
};

/** 
 * Docs for class
 */
class MyClass 
{
    static struct MyStruct instance; ///< Docs for instance
};
```

Otherwise, if you want to use the `///<` comments, you have to put the comment after the semicolon of the declaration:

```
struct MyStruct 
{
    std::string a; ///< Docs for a
    std::string b; ///< Docs for b
}; ///< Docs for struct

class MyClass 
{
    static struct MyStruct instance; ///< Docs for instance
}; ///< Docs for class
```

Comment: While _techically_ this does make the warning go away, it instead produces a spurious entry for `firstVal` in the actual generated documentation, which is clearly worse. (Also my non-toy code uses `/** */` style comments everywhere, I just stuffed it all on one line for more readable sample code)

Comment: @Alec Sorry,I didn't recognize the "attribute" entry, I just looked after the documentation of `MyStruct` which looked fine. And regarding my tip: I just meant well with you, since the sample code you sent produces some unwanted characters in the documentation.